# How do mathematicians think about multivectors/exterior algebra?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I recently came across the notion of multivectors and exterior algebras recently and while I find these notions to be very enlightening, I also feel a strong temptation to interpret these objects too geometrically (at least for my taste).

My current understanding is this:

Given a (finite dimensional) vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and a choice of basis $\mathcal{B}=\{e_{1},...,e_{n}\}$ we can define the notion of orientation. If we let $V =\mathbb{R}^{2}$ then in some sense, we can think of a vector as a "measure" with a direction and this direction depends on a choice of basis (usually the canonical basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$). In a vector space $V$, we can add vectors $u,v \in V$ together to create new vectors $u+v \in V$ and multiply vectors by elements of $\mathbb{F}$ to create "new" vectors $\alpha u+ \beta v \in V$ for $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{F}$.

However, we cannot multiply vectors together to get another vector unless we define an algebra $\Lambda(V)$ over $\mathbb{F}$ which in addition to the properties of a vector space, gives us a new binary operation $\wedge:V \times V \to \Lambda(V)$ such that $$u \wedge v = -v \wedge u \in \Lambda(V)$$ and $$u \wedge (v \wedge w)=(u \wedge v) \wedge w=u \wedge v \wedge w \in \Lambda(V)$$ and furthermore we have
$$
(\alpha_{1} e_{1} + \beta_{1} e_{2})\wedge(\alpha_{2} e_{1}+\beta_{2} e_{2})=\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2} e_{1} \wedge e_{1}+\alpha_{1}\beta_{2}e_{1} \wedge e_{2}+\beta_{1}\alpha_{2} e_{2} \wedge e_{1}+\beta_{1}\beta_{2}e_{2} \wedge e_{2}
$$ 
which then gives us
$$
(\alpha_{1}\beta_{2}-\beta_{1}\alpha_{2})e_{1} \wedge e_{2}
$$
so $\Lambda(V)$ is anticommutative with respect to $\wedge$, $\wedge$ is associative and $\wedge$ distributes over (vector) addition.

Now my problem is with the geometric intuition\interpretation behind these objects. Basically, with a vector you are constrained to the geometric interpretation of "directed line segment". However, for $u,v \in V$, we have $u \wedge v \in \Lambda(V)$, which is no longer a vector but a *bivector* which seems like it can be interpreted as a "measure" with an  orientation. If we take $V=\mathbb{R}^{2}$, we can interpret $u \wedge v$ as the area of the parallelogram in the picture [image]

However, it isn't the shape that is so important but the area and the orientation induced by the exterior product. So my understanding is that a *bivector* can be informally thought of as an equivalence class of regions in the plane with the same area and the same orientation. However, as a mathematician (in training) this amount of geometric reasoning doesn't sit right with me.

On one hand, I know that I just need to put the geometric aspects aside and think of $u \wedge v$ as an abstract object in $\Lambda(V)$ but I also fear that if I don't get the geometric intuition, I am going to miss out on the insights behind Clifford/Geometric Algebra down the road (should I ever venture there). I was hoping some of the more experienced mathematicians on here could give me some insight on the matter or any books (with a mathematical perspective rather than physical) that might help me see this area of mathematics clearer?

Comment: For geometry, think also of its dual.

Comment: Your intuition of a bivector as a plane together with a distinguished choice of oriented area (the two-dimensional analogue of a unit of length) is good. J.W. Gibbs' [_On Multiple Algebra_](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/50977) (the transcript of an 1886 lecture to the AAAS) may be worth a look for physical motivation (if not geometric intuition).

Comment: Keep in mind that in 4d you can have bivectors that cannot be written as the outer product of two vectors.